# What is the difference between Char and Word8?

Tags: sml

The Standard ML Basis Library has a `Char` structure and a `Word8` structure. A `Char.char` always represents 8 bits and a `Word8.word` always represents 8 bits. There is a one-to-one mapping between the values of these two types, so why are both needed? It seems rather unnecessary to have to explicitly convert between these two essentially equivalent types by using `Byte.byteToChar` and `Byte.charToByte`. A similar situation exists for `String.string` and `Word8Vector.vector`.

Comment: "For implementations where the underlying representation of the `Word8Vector.vector` and `string` types are the same, these functions should be constant-time operations." This implies that while they can be the same thing, there can be architectures where they are not. For example, many decades ago, a char was 7 bits.

Comment: I'm happy they've kept them separate. It would mix things up to say that chars and bytes are the same thing, even though the underlying representation of chars needs just one byte. But everything is bytes after all! And I wouldn't like to read code like `#"A" << 2` or `Word8.toUpper byte`.

Comment: Neither represents eight bits, but both use eight bits to store what they represent. That is, they're not equivalent – one represents a character and the other represents an unsigned integer. The letter A and the number 65 are not the same thing, even if the letter happens to be encoded as 65 in some character encoding. That these two types have the same size is incidental and irrelevant to their meaning.